# Configure NextCloud & Nginx Reverse Port Forward - Login Authentication Error

Tags: nginx

I have set up an nginx reverse proxy server on my web server, which is receiving SSL traffic, and reverse proxying it to port 8080 on my web server, which is an exposed port running the nextcloud docker image. I am able to log in from a desktop web browser, but I am not able to log in from my iPhone. When I log in from the app, I receive error message "Access Forbidden, Invalid Request." [This](https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/8956) Github issue identifies the issue as auth headers being removed from the request, though the solution it gives is for Apache, not for Nginx. I'm really not familiar with authorization headers. How would I modify my Nginx server directive to take care of the issue?

**Current setup**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name cloud.foo.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cloud.foo.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cloud.foo.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/;

        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    }
}
```

Comment: I an not sure if Nginx strips the `Authorization` response header, but I have seen another cloud service specify the following for reverse proxies. Try adding: `proxy_pass_header Authorization;`

Comment: Sounds like an answer to me :) Want to set it as one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add a setting to explicitly pass the `Authorization` header in the response from the proxied server.

For example:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/;

    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_pass_header  Authorization;
}
```

Based on the reverse proxy settings I've seen for another authenticated service, it's probable that by default, Nginx does not pass the `Authorization` header from the response of a proxied server to a client. Although this is not listed in [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_hide_header), it is probably necessary to avoid interference with the [authentication modules](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html).